# ATtiny44 not responding to AVRISP mkII programmer

Tags: avr

It's not responding to the programmer at all in avr studio.

```
avrisp     attiny44
mosi  -- - mosi
miso  ---- miso
sck   ---- usck
reset ----  reset
```

Or can it not be programmed by an mk2? I assumed all chips can be programmed by it

Comment: Did you connect the two grounds together also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AVRISP mkII can program the tiny44 in the latest version of AVR Studio (4.18 SP3 or 5 beta).  Make sure your version is either up-to-date or check the help files/release notes that came with it to verify.  Also allow AVR Studio to update the firmware in your AVRISP mkII if it needs to.

Verify the following conditions:

- Programmer is connected to PCB (GND, RESET, MOSI, MISO, and SCK)
- Target is powered.

  - Not sure how much power the AVRISP MKII can provide, but don't rely on it if your board takes more than 50 mA.
  - You do *not* need to connect the programmer's VCC line to the chip power if you provide it externally.
- MOSI, MISO, SCK have pullups to GND/VCC no stronger than 820 Ω.
- RESET pullup should be no stronger than 4.7 kΩ and have a decoupling capacitor less than 10 µF.

Follow the troubleshooting guide in the [AVRISP mkII user guide](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/AVRISPmkII_UG.pdf) [PDF] if you experience problems as a first step:

[image]

Comment: I was told the vcc and gnd is used as detecting the logic level am using. It  doesn't provide power. is that not true